# 5 card major bridge

Tags: bridge, bidding

Playing 5 card major, a weak NT, rubber bridge. After a 1NT opening, west bids 2 clubs (interfering) - opener's partner bids 2 hearts - is this still a weakness takeout (i.e. Limit bid telling declarer got weak hand with max 9 pts and 5 in bid suit)or does West's bid take that out? I.e. Does declarer treat the 2 hearts as a normal bid?

Answer (score 3):

As is always the case for questions about the meanings of bids, the answer depends on agreements between you and your partner.  You can agree to whatever you want, and in many cases, including this one, there isn't some choice of agreements that stands out as being much better than the alternatives.

That being said, I think it is slightly better to agree to make this a weak takeout, except that you will pass on the weakest hands unless you have a club singleton.  If you are playing transfer bids, most people keep them over an intervening bid of 2 clubs (with double asking for a 4 card major).

The main reason this is better is that you would rather be down 1 (even doubled) at 2 hearts than let them make 2 clubs and have a leg towards game, and similarly, you would rather get a leg with making 2 hearts than set them at 2 clubs.